# Как изменить цвет фона у Floating Action Mode?

Tags: android, background-color

Как изменить цвет фона у Floating Action Mode в android приложении?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант добавить в стиль темы такую запись:

```
<item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/dark_red</item>
```

[вот здесь](https://medium.com/over-engineering/using-androids-actionmode-e903181f2ee3) хорошо описано как работать с контекстным меню. Если же речь идет о цвете выделения, то его можно установить добавив поле в EditText:

```
android:textColorHighlight="#ff0000"
```

либо программно добавить к текстовому полю:

```
et.setHighlightColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.highlight));
```

Comment: <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/dark_red</item> не работает для фона Floating Action Mode.

Comment: я уточню этот вариант решения вашей проблемы